# dictionary middle norwegian

Tags: germanic-languages, norwegian

I try to help somebody with research on the influence of Middle Low German on Middle Norwegian.

For that purpose, a number of documents from the Norwegian Corpus ([Diplomatarium Norvegicum]) are examined, especially documents from Bergen between 1350 and 1550.

There are about 20 sentences (from different documents) on which we need help translating.

Does anybody have any links to a dictionary for the middle-Norwegian from that time-periode?

Thanks!

(Update: 28/7/18)
Here are a couple of sentences. Perhaps this can help determine what dictionary can be used for this:

> oc thet thennom aff ingen beffallingsmendt eller nogen anden haffuer
> formeint veriit før end nu y høst forledenn at forne fru Sophie vden
> all rett rettergang low dom eller nogen redelig arsage
>
> och schall ether nade ingen twiffuel haffue att ether nade schall
> bliffue forsømmett wdj nogenn the maade som i myn forstandt eller
> macht er.
>
> att ingen landbo nødgas schall aff hans landråtte på nogen långsam
> reese vten han thet wælwilleligh gøræ will men dogh skulle alle
> landboor pliictuge ware fløte

Kr.

Comment: It is possible that *Norrøn ordbok* (Heggstad, Hødnebø & Simensen) contains what you need. http://www.edd.uio.no/perl/search/search.cgi was not very useful, but I didn't spend much time trying to make it work